# Returning multiple lines formatted without an extra blank line at the end

Tags: python, string, return

I'm trying to return several separate lines of text from a function with nice formatting. The way I'm doing it currently adds an extra line at the end that I don't want. How can I format this better?

```
def myfunction():
    mystring = ''
    for letter in 'cat':
        mystring += letter + '\n'
    return mystring
```

Right now the output is:

```
c
a
t
<this is a blank line at the end>
```

How can I get rid of that blank line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by [@vaultah (in the comments)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45121729/returning-multiple-lines-formatted-without-an-extra-blank-line-at-the-end/45121765#comment77214260_45121729) you should use [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) instead of string addition. `join` also takes care of the trailing newline:

```
def myfunction():
    return '\n'.join('cat')
```

Note that string addition is generally a bad idea, because it involves a lot of reallocations and can be much slower than `str.join`.

Comment: The suggestion was quite trivial, you really didn't have to add the attribution...